# VS Code Pytest/Unittest debugger doesn't stop on breakpoints

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest, python-unittest, django-unittest

I wrote unittest-based tests with pytest. according to this document:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/unittest.html
then I tried to run the tests by Python testing in Visual Studio Code according to this document:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing
but when I select the Debug Test icon next to that test in the Test Explorer. VS Code starts the debugger but it doesn't pause at the breakpoints. how can I make it to stop at the breakpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to what has been explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/693), when we use "--cov" option for pytest, the VSCode doesn't stop at breakpoints. So the solution is to disable cov while debugging according to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/693#issuecomment-926591721) in your VSCode launch.json add the followings:

```
   // your other settings are here
   {
    "name": "Debug Unit Test",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "justMyCode": true,
    "program": "${file}",
    "purpose": ["debug-test"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "env": {
        "PYTEST_ADDOPTS": "--no-cov"
    },
}
```